# Uploading image and adding link to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, content-management-system

Im creating a CMS for my site and in my admin page I have an add page that adds new content to my site [LOCATED HERE](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2) and have added a few form fields.

2 of these are:

IMAGE URL (text box) & UPLOAD IMAGE (select file button)

When I fill in all the fileds and select an image using IMAGE URL and hit add article, it works fine and my form is saved to my database and is then displayed on my site.

When I fill in all the fileds and select an image using UPLOAD IMAGE and hit add article, it adds the image to my selected folder in my cpanel but DOES NOT ADD TO DATABASE.

My question is: **How can I get it to add to the database? and save the new images location to the image field on the database?**

I have followed this tutorial when adding the upload file button to my page.

Please do not show me links on how to do this as I already have read through them but I stuggle when it comes to adding this to my code.

my add.php code is this.

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
  if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
        $title   = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
        if (!empty($_POST['image']))
        {
            $image = $_POST['image'];
        }
        else
        {
            $image = $_POST['imageupload'];

            if (isset($_FILES['imageupload']))
            {
              $errors = array();
              $allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

              $file_name = $_FILES['imageupload'] ['name'];
              $file_ext = strtolower (end (explode ('.', $file_name)));
              $file_size = $_FILES['imageupload'] ['size'];
              $file_tmp = $_FILES['imageupload'] ['tmp_name'];

              if (in_array ($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
                     $errors[] = 'File extension not allowed';
              }

              if ($file_size > 2097152) {
                     $errors[] = 'File size must be under 2mb';
              }

              if (empty($errors)) {
                     if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'images/'.$file_name)) {
                           echo 'File uploaded';
                           $image = $file_name;
              }
              }else{
                    foreach ($errors as $error)
                    echo $error, '<br />';
              }

            }
        }
        $link     = $_POST['link'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $brand    = $_POST['brand'];


if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
         $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
}else{
 $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mobi (promo_title, promo_content, promo_image, promo_link, promo_cat, promo_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
 $query->bindValue(1, $title);
 $query->bindValue(2, $content);
 $query->bindValue(3, $image);
 $query->bindValue(4, $link);
 $query->bindValue(5, $category);
 $query->bindValue(6, $brand);



     $query->execute();
    header('location: index.php');
}

}
          ?>
    <?php

if (isset($_FILES['Filedata']))
{
// And if it was ok
    if ($_FILES['Filedata']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    exit('Upload failed. Error code: ' . $_FILES['image']['error']);

    $filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $targetpath    = "../img/news/" . $filename; //target directory relative to script location

    $copy = copy($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $targetpath);
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Add Article</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../other.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo"><b>&larr; Back</b></a>

<br />

<div align="center">
<h4>Add Article</h4>

<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
     <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
<?php } ?>

<form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" placeholder="Content" name="content"></textarea><br /><br />
<input name="imageupload" type="file" id="image" placeholder="Imageupload" />
<input type="text" name="image" placeholder="Image" /><br /><br />
<input type="link" name="link" placeholder="Link" /><br /><br />
<input type="category" name="category" placeholder="Category" /><br /><br />
<input type="category" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Article" />

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
}else{
       header('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'images/'.$file_name)) {
                       echo 'File uploaded';                          
           $image = '/images/'.$filename;//try updating the line like this
```